# How to change number format in DataGrip table editor

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I'm wondering, why DataGrip not respecting local number format separators, when editing table values.

Here in Germany our decimal separator is a comma, not a dot. And so I can't use my keypad to edit numbers.

Has anyone a idea, how to change number format?

Comment: There is no possibility like this, but we have an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2159

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who is looking for a solution not to edit but **to export data** using a specified decimal separator:

You can create a user defined data extractor (e.g. like [this example](https://gist.github.com/siggibjarna/ca15688a319771a309078fdd4577deee)) and [use it in DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/export-data-in-ide.html#creating-any-text-extractor-with).

Comment: This works great, and DataGrip makes it easy to extend and add extractors. Of course changing of the decimal separator should be easy to set without coding. I am aware that DG is the programmers tool, like all Jet Brain products, but basic things should be included. In the code provided it is easy to change also other things to your preference.